# How to pass a value to a Pluggable View?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am trying to implement a template for adding VIEW, ADD and EDIT webpages with pluggable views. How do I use a url value like ?

This is the code I am trying to translate into pluggable views.

```
@app.route('/edit/category/<category>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editCategory(category):
    form = forms.AddCategory()
    form.name.data = category
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newName = form.name.data
        database.editCategory(name = category, newName = newName)
        #view single category?
        return redirect('/view/categories/')
    return render_template('edit-category.html', category = category, form = form)
```

Pluggable View Code

```
class ListView(View):

    def getTemplate_name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def render_template(self, context):
        return render_template(self.get_template_name(), **context)

    def dispatch_request(self):
        context = self.get_context()
        return self.render_template(context)

class CategoryView(ListView):

    def get_template_name(self):
        return 'categories.html'

    def get_objects(self):
        return models.Category.query.all()

    def get_form(self):
        return forms.AddCategory()

    def get_context(self):
        return {'categories': self.get_objects(), 'form': self.get_form()}

app.add_url_rule('/view/categories', view_func=CategoryView.as_view('category'))

class EditCategory(ListView):

    def get_template_name(self):
        return 'edit-category.html'

    def get_form(self, category):
        form = forms.AddCategory()
        form.name.data = category
        return form

    def get_context(self):
        return {'form': self.get_form()}

app.add_url_rule('/edit/category/<category>', view_func=EditCategory.as_view('category'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `dispatch_request` method in the `EditCategory` class as this method has the url values passed to it.

```
class EditCategory(View):

    ...

    def get_context(self, category):
        return {'form': self.get_form(category)}

    def dispatch_request(self, category):
        context = self.get_context(category)
        return self.render_template(context)

app.add_url_rule('/edit/category/<category>', view_func=EditCategory.as_view('category'))
```

As an aside, I think you are better off with the original decorated view functions in this case is there is very little commonality between the `viewCategory` and `editCategory` functionality